# wpf binding support save many to many objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I'm a new to WPF (c#) and trying to work with MVVM.
Here is the challenge that I have:
Suppose I have two listboxs the one containing product names and the other 
have product parameters. The product parameters is name and value (textbox or checkbox).
 
User wants to be able:
1.To chose the product and see and edit it's parameters. option to edit some of the parameters and bnot all.
2.To chose several products and edit several parameters for them.
In other words, support one to one, one to many, many to many,many to one.

The listbox is only an idea you can propose other control/s.
How can I do it with binding and is there a good example for it?
Thanks.

Comment: @lgal Can you add some code from your `viewmodel` and anything else that may help us answer?

Comment: Actually I'm in design stage and don't have code yet. I'm looking for a basic concept because I don't know how to start. please help. thanks.

Comment: Your question is kinda generic, we'd need more details, although I'm sure that if you have an object `Product` containing all details, you can just define a `TwoWay` binding your `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<Product>` would do the trick for you, you'd just have to bind appropriate `TextBox`es to your product's details and all will be updated automatically (this is teh true powerzz of DataBinding :) )

Comment: Yes, it is generic question. I understand you suggestion but my main challenge is how to do the many to many connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" x:Name="customersList"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="customersDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=customersList,Path=SelectedItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <PropertyGrid IsEditable ="{Binding CanEditCustomer}" SelectedItem ="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The first list contains all customers.
The second list contains editors for properties of selected customers.